# I cannot pass data as a variable when using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cannot pass data as a variable when using Ajax.

The following code works fine:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'test10.php',
    data: { name:'Donald', town:'Ducktown' },
});
```

The code below does not work:

```
var new_names = ("name:'Donald', town:'Ducktown'") ;
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'test10.php',
    data: { new_names },
});
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You have to assign a value to new_names. Objects (the {} defines a new object) are hashmaps and without a value it doesn't know what you want to do.

Comment: `var new_names = ("name:'Donald', town:'Ducktown'") ;` <-- change `("` to `{` and `")` to `}`. Objects, in javascripts, are descripted inside the `{`, not `(`. Also, instead of `data: { new_names },`, to **match the above example's logic**, just do: `data: new_names,`, else you will parse a nested object: `{ { new_names } }`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because it's not the same thing.  The first example has this as the data object:

```
{ name:'Donald', town:'Ducktown' }
```

Which is a valid object.  If we re-factor the second example, we can simplify it down to essentially a syntax error.  Starting with what you have:

```
var new_names = ("name:'Donald', town:'Ducktown'");
//...
{
    data: { new_names }
}
```

First remove the parentheses, since they don't actually do anything here:

```
var new_names = "name:'Donald', town:'Ducktown'";
//...
{
    data: { new_names }
}
```

Then remove the use of a variable as temporary storage:

```
{
    data: { "name:'Donald', town:'Ducktown'" }
}
```

And you can see why it becomes a problem.  This is just a string literal in brackets, and not a valid object (or even valid syntax, though the use of the variable as temporary storage may somehow get it to pass the parser).  You could make the string itself a *value* on an object:

```
{ someValue: "name:'Donald', town:'Ducktown'" }
```

But I doubt that's what you want.  If you just want to store the object in a variable, then why change the notation?  Just store it as a variable like you already use it:

```
var new_names = { name:'Donald', town:'Ducktown' };
```

Then use the variable:

```
data: new_names
```

There's no reason to modify the notation or throw in extra quotes or brackets.  A literal object is a literal object, as-is.  Whether you use it in-line or store it in a variable and use the variable, the notation to define the literal object itself doesn't change.

Comment: You didn't properly copy the example. Yours is a syntax error, you can't put a string in an object literal like this.

Comment: upvote for addressing **all** the problems related to the question, including extra `"` and nested object.

Comment: @DenysSéguret: In what way is it functionally different from the original?  I would expect the parentheses to not really do much in the second original example, and the expression defining the variable would simply define it as a string.  Can you clarify the difference?

Comment: @David `("...")` is just a string literal. `{"..."}` is a syntax error in that assignement. This is **very** different.

Comment: @DenysSéguret: Yes... it's an error being made in the question.  And addressed in this answer.

Comment: You still don't get it... You write *"The second example has this: { "name:'Donald', town:'Ducktown'" }"*. The second example doesn't have this because it would be a syntax error. Read again the question "(" is very different from "{". This is NOT the "functional equivalent".

Comment: Thank you David fro your quick reply. Your suggestion works great!

Comment: @DenysSéguret: I've updated the text of the answer to clarify.  I had removed the use of the variable to illustrate *why* what the OP was doing was incorrect.  I understand that it *is* incorrect, and am providing an answer to suggest how to *make it* correct.  That's kind of what Stack Overflow does.

Comment: @Menachem: Glad we could help!

Answer (score 0):

2 errors:

```
var new_names = {name:'Donald', town:'Ducktown'}; // create a proper literal
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'test10.php',
    data: new_names, // don't put braces here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

replace '(' for '{'

```
var new_names = {name:'Donald', town:'Ducktown'} ;
```

and remove '{' in data

```
   data: new_names
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. replacing '(' for '{' and removing '{' from the data: solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the data as an object instead of a string:

```
var new_names = {name:'Donald', town:'Ducktown'} ;
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'test10.php',
    data: new_names,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake here is you need to pass an object, check the correct code:

```
var new_names = {name:'Donald', town:'Ducktown'};
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'test10.php',
    data: new_names,
});
```

or you can do this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'test10.php',
        data: {name:'Donald', town:'Ducktown'},
    });
```